# How do I tell Spotlight not to index a particular folder?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, spotlight

I don't want to turn Spotlight off completely, I just want to turn it off for one particular folder in my homedir called 'nospotlight`

[Another question](https://superuser.com/questions/35983/how-to-disable-spotlight-in-snow-leopard) talks about how to disable Spotlight completely; but I want to keep it running, just not indexing one particular folder.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can add that folder to the [Spotlight privacy list](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=Mac/10.4/en/mh2160.html).

> 1. Open System Preferences and click Spotlight.
> 2. Click Privacy.
> 3. Drag folders or disks to add them to the Privacy list, or click the Add
>      (+) button to browse for an item.
> 4. To remove an item, select it and click Delete (-).

Answer (score 1):

You can add an empty file named `.metadata_never_index` to a folder.

Or you can suffix the folder name with `.noindex` — e.g. `Trip Photos.noindex`

Sources: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/258791 | https://www.techjunkie.com/three-ways-to-prevent-spotlight-from-indexing-items-on-your-mac/