# Mac OS X Spotlight: how to stop it from indexing SD cards

Tags: macos, mac, spotlight

I tried the approach in [How do I tell Spotlight not to index a particular folder?](https://superuser.com/questions/89527/how-do-i-tell-spotlight-not-to-index-a-particular-folder) but it still indexes my SD card when I reinsert it into my card reader.

How do I stop this, either for all SD cards or for a particular one?

---

**edit:** It looks like I can do this either with that method or with `mdutil`, but I also need to delete all the hidden dotfiles (.Spotlight-V100 .Trashes ._.Trashes and .fseventsd) from the SD card -- this is for my Garmin GPS and the GPS somehow doesn't like the dotfiles.

When I delete those dotfiles, Mac OS X forgets that I have disabled Spotlight on the card.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How disable mac snow leopard creating .Spotlight-V100 and .Trash folders in USB Flash Drivers?](http://superuser.com/questions/89556/how-disable-mac-snow-leopard-creating-spotlight-v100-and-trash-folders-in-usb)

Answer (score 3):

See [this site](http://www.pengekcs.com/2007/12/25/taming-spotlight-to-not-index-specific-external-drives-at-all-in-os-x/) for the simple answer: create a file named .metadata_never_index in the root of the volume (once it is mounted).

Comment: I believe he doesn't want *any* dotfiles on the external drive.

Comment: Maybe one empty dotfile is better than several non-empty ones? The files he mentions are non-empty...

Comment: Maybe. Couldn't hurt to try I suppose :)

Comment: I'm not sure how to deal with the issue... it's a moot point (for now) since I reformatted the card on a PC and haven't touched it with my Mac.

Comment: Hmmm. This answer only prevents the .Spotlight-V100 directory, not the other dotfiles (.fseventsd, .Trashes ._.Trashes).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no easy way to do this. But there is a utility that can prevent these files from being written called [Blue Harvest](http://www.zeroonetwenty.com/blueharvest/).

**Edit:** Here is a free solution called [Hidden Cleaner](http://www.macupdate.com/info.php/id/27416/hidden-cleaner).