# How to disable Spotlight content indexing in Mac OS

Tags: macos, osx-lion, spotlight

From Windows experience, I could always elect Live search to only index file names *not* their content. Is this something that can be done with Spotlight on a Mac?

It used to index *absolutely everything*, for instance it would return a bunch of video files for any obscure character combination typed into the search field.

Right now I've disabled Spotlight entirely [as per this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/35983/how-to-disable-spotlight-in-snow-leopard), but it seems to have disabled searching altogether. For instance, Finder is yet to locate any `.pdf` files in a small directory as I'm typing this question (unlike windows search which would still be able to work even with indexing disabled)

Alternatively, if there is any way (including a trusted third-party app) that will index file names *and metadata* e.g. ID3 tags that would likely be the preferred option.

Comment: spotlight does not index content it only indexes metadata of a file, for each file type there is a spotlight plugin that is used to get information about the file *which might include more data than you would expect from Windows) and as you notice Apple uses spotlight for all searching

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use a third party search engine. The few parameters of spotlight are in the system preferences.

My company publishes [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com) which is an open source search engine software able to handle complex indexation strategies, including mp3 tag indexation. May be you can have a look.