# Reenabling the Spotlight Menubar item in Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, spotlight

I believe I followed the [instructions here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20091030173117381) to disable Spotlight indexing and remove the menubar item.

I reenabled indexing just fine, but when I changed the permissions back to 744, the spotlight search *position* came back (as in the space it would normally occupy), but the actual icon and search box will not show up.  If I click that portion of the screen I get a blue box, but I can't type anything in to anything.

Currently, permissions look like this:

```
[~]$ ll /System/Library/CoreServices/Search.bundle.bak/Contents/MacOS/
total 648
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel   835K Sep 17 14:48 Search*
```

`ll` is an alias mapped to the following

```
alias ll='${LS_PREAMBLE} -hl'
```

with $LS_PREAMBLE

```
[~]$ echo $LS_PREAMBLE
ls -GF
```

(Ignore the .bak extension.  I decided that until I found a way to fully restore it, I would just remove it entirely following the [directions here](https://superuser.com/questions/32593/remove-spotlight-icon-from-the-menu-bar))

That looks right to me and obviously something is launching, but the UI elements aren't there.

So how can I restore it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Spotlight.icns` should be in the `Resources` directory of `Search.bundle/Contents`.

If you're experiencing difficulties with the UI not showing up, perhaps you should check that the `Resources` directory *exists at all*!

Luckily I was able to find a copy of the Resources directory and place it back in the proper location. Everything appears fine now.

Comment: Interesting. The patch brought back the `Search.bundle`, but not all its contents -- I only got a `nib` file in the Spanish locale in `Resources`. That's why it works only partially -- the bundle is there, but no resources.

Answer (score 0):

Is that really your `ls` output? Because that file should be `Search`, not `Search*`.

Once everything in the filesystem is back to the way it should be, I might just try restarting for kicks, and a permissions repair.

If all else fails, try restoring Search.bundle from backup.

Comment: The asterisk at the end is most likely from the `-F` option to ls. It just indicates that this is an executable file -- which the permissions also show.

Comment: It is indeed my `ls` output.  I'll try repairing permissions.

Comment: On further review, I appear to be _missing_ `Spotlight.icns` from my System! I'm running a `sudo find / -name "Spolight.icns"` as I write, but Spotlight itself turns up nothing. Where should I be looking for the Icon file and how could I go about restoring it if it's indeed missing?